# New empty Widgets for every new day in calendar Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have an app where I want to save some events at a certain date. Top Button opens the calendar, "Add New Event" Button adds a new event in GridLayout.
First problem, I can't show the current date on the Top Button. I can show any date, but not the current date when the app starts.
Secondly I want for every new date (or new day), an empty GridLayout, where I can add new events, or to complete the old ones, and maybe later on to save all that stuff.
Thanks a lot!!
Python code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker

class MyBox(BoxLayout):
    def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.ids.date.text = str(value)
    def show_date(self):
        date = MDDatePicker()
        date.bind(on_save= self.on_save)
        date.open()
    def add_item(self):
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.ids.grd_id.add_widget(EventTemplate())
class EventTemplate(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyAppApp(MDApp):
    pass

MyAppApp().run()
```

KV code:

```
MyBox:
<MyBox>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        id: date
        size_hint: 1, 0.2
        on_release: root.show_date()
    ScrollView:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.minimum_height
            id: grd_id
            spacing: 10
            cols: 1

            EventTemplate:
            EventTemplate:

    Button:
        on_release: root.add_item()
        size_hint: 1, 0.2
        text: "Add New Event"

<EventTemplate>:
    size_hint_y: None
    spacing: 1
    CheckBox:
        size_hint: 0.1, 1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
    Label:
        text: "Some Event"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `on_start()` method to your `MyAppApp`:

```
def on_start(self):
    self.root.ids.date.text = str(datetime.date.today())
```